# Is it possible to loop through multiple elements and then add another element to each of the selected elements?

Tags: javascript, html

For example, can I put `<h1>` inside two separate `<div>` elements using a loop? 
I know you can just use the function to append the element but I was wondering if you can use a loop to achieve this.

I have tried this but it only selects the first div.

## HTML

```
<div id="event1" class="yellow"></div>
<div id="event2" class="blue"></div>
```

## JAVASCRIPT

```
function myElement(tag, msg) {
  var h1 = document.createElement(tag);
  var text = document.createTextNode(msg);
  h1.appendChild(text);
  return h1;
}

var eventHolder = document.createElement("div");
var event = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

for (var i = 0; i < event.length; i++) {
    eventHolder.appendChild(myElement("h1", "events"));
    document.getElementsByTagName("div")[i].appendChild(eventHolder);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `document.getElementsByTagName("div");` will be a live collection of every `div` in the document. When you insert another `div`, its length will be increased. The error that results is

> Uncaught HierarchyRequestError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': The new child element contains the parent.

Live collections are weird. Loop over and append to elements of a static collection instead:

```js
function myElement(tag, msg) {
  var h1 = document.createElement(tag);
  var text = document.createTextNode(msg);
  h1.appendChild(text);
  return h1;
}

var eventHolder = document.createElement("div");
var event = document.querySelectorAll("div");

for (var i = 0; i < event.length; i++) {
  eventHolder.appendChild(myElement("h1", "events"));
  event[i].appendChild(eventHolder);
}
```

```html
<div id="event1" class="yellow"></div>
<div id="event2" class="blue"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A loop can be used to append elements to multiple tags,

If you check your console you should get `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': The new child element contains the parent.`

`var eventHolder = document.createElement("div");` This is a div, this hasn't been attached to the DOM yet.

`var event = document.getElementsByTagName("div");` This is an array of all divs currently attached to the DOM -  In our case 2.

`eventHolder.appendChild(myElement("h1", "events"));` Here you append a newly created h1 element to the earlier created div `eventHolder`

`document.getElementsByTagName("div")[i].appendChild(eventHolder);` This line retrieves all the divs in the DOM afresh and appends the newly created element based on the index

**The Problem**

1. On the first loop we have 2 divs in the DOM, the index is at 0 so it appends a new element to first one
2. Note that you are appending a div `eventHolder` and so on the second loop it fetches all divs again (now 3) which includes the new div, and tries to append `eventHolder` again
3. The solution would be to stop fetching the divs in the DOM on every loop, so if there are (2) divs in the DOM only those divs will be processed in the loop this means using the `events` variable

The answer by @Snow is correct, this is just an explanation